# What URL escaping does GitHub markdown expect?

Tags: github, links, url, markdown

I have a markdown file checked into GitHub, and in this file I want to link to the following URL:

> https://query.wikidata.org/#%23 Diplomatic missions with no operator.%0ASELECT DISTINCT%0A%09%3Fwikidata%0A%09(SAMPLE(%3Ftype_label) as %3Ftype)%0A%09(SAMPLE(%3Fcountry_label) as %3Fcountry)%09%0AWHERE {%0A%09{ %3Fwikidata p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279* wd%3AQ3917681. } UNION { %3Fwikidata p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279* wd%3AQ7843791. } %23 Embassy or consulate%0A%09%3Fwikidata p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31 %3FtypeId. %3FtypeId wdt%3AP279* wd%3AQ43229. %3FtypeId rdfs%3Alabel %3Ftype_label. FILTER (lang(%3Ftype_label) %3D "en").%0A%09%3Fwikidata wdt%3AP131* %3Farea .%0A%09%3Farea wdt%3AP17 %3FcountryId. %3FcountryId rdfs%3Alabel %3Fcountry_label. FILTER (lang(%3Fcountry_label) %3D "en").%0A%09MINUS{%0A %09{%3Fwikidata wdt%3AP137 %3FoperatorId.}%0A %09UNION%0A%09%09{%3Fwikidata p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31 %3Fnunciature. %3Fnunciature wdt%3AP137 %3FoperatorId.}%0A }%0A%09MINUS {%3Fwikidata wdt%3AP582 %3Fendtime.}%09 MINUS {%3Fwikidata wdt%3AP582 %3FdissolvedOrAbolished.}%0A%09MINUS {%3Fwikidata p%3AP31 %3FinstanceStatement. %3FinstanceStatement pq%3AP582 %3FendtimeQualifier.}%0A%09%23 Only countries that still contain the location (ex%3A Pristina is not in the "Province of Kosovo" because it does not exist anymore.%0A%09FILTER NOT EXISTS {%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata p%3AP131%2F(ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)* %3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3Fstatement ps%3AP131 %3Farea.%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata p%3AP131%2F(ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)* %3FintermediateStatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement (ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)* %3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement pq%3AP582 %3FendTime.%0A%09}%0A} GROUP BY %3Fwikidata

Unfortunately, GitHub fails to understand the link, the link appears as text.
I tried replacing all spaces with `%20`, it does not work either:

```
[Find embassies lacking an operator](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Diplomatic%20missions%20with%20no%20operator.%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%0A%09%3Fwikidata%0A%09(SAMPLE(%3Ftype_label)%20as%20%3Ftype)%0A%09(SAMPLE(%3Fcountry_label)%20as%20%3Fcountry)%09%0AWHERE%20{%0A%09{%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ3917681.%20}%20UNION%20{%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ7843791.%20}%20%23%20Embassy%20or%20consulate%0A%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3FtypeId.%20%3FtypeId%20wdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ43229.%20%3FtypeId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftype_label.%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Ftype_label)%20%3D%20"en").%0A%09%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP131*%20%3Farea%20.%0A%09%3Farea%20wdt%3AP17%20%3FcountryId.%20%3FcountryId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_label.%20FILTER%20(lang(%3Fcountry_label)%20%3D%20"en").%0A%09MINUS{%0A%20%09{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP137%20%3FoperatorId.}%0A%20%09UNION%0A%09%09{%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3Fnunciature.%20%3Fnunciature%20wdt%3AP137%20%3FoperatorId.}%0A%20}%0A%09MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP582%20%3Fendtime.}%09%20MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP582%20%3FdissolvedOrAbolished.}%0A%09MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%20%3FinstanceStatement.%20%3FinstanceStatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendtimeQualifier.}%0A%09%23%20Only%20countries%20that%20still%20contain%20the%20location%20(ex%3A%20Pristina%20is%20not%20in%20the%20"Province%20of%20Kosovo"%20because%20it%20does%20not%20exist%20anymore.%0A%09FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20{%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP131%2F(ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)*%20%3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP131%20%3Farea.%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP131%2F(ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)*%20%3FintermediateStatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement%20(ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131)*%20%3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendTime.%0A%09}%0A}%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fwikidata)
```

How to escape the URL so that GitHub markdown correctly creates the link?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to encode your parentheses in order for GitHub to correctly parse the link. You can see this by typing the bare URL into the GitHub editor. GitHub will underline a natively-typed link, but in yours it only underlines up to the first open parentheses:

[image]

Replacing your open parentheses `(` with `%28` and your close parentheses `)` with `%29` will allow GitHub to correctly process the link.  The updated URL would be:

`https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Diplomatic%20missions%20with%20no%20operator.%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%0A%09%3Fwikidata%0A%09%28SAMPLE%28%3Ftype_label%29%20as%20%3Ftype%29%0A%09%28SAMPLE%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20as%20%3Fcountry%29%09%0AWHERE%20{%0A%09{%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ3917681.%20}%20UNION%20{%20%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ7843791.%20}%20%23%20Embassy%20or%20consulate%0A%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3FtypeId.%20%3FtypeId%20wdt%3AP279*%20wd%3AQ43229.%20%3FtypeId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Ftype_label.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Ftype_label%29%20%3D%20"en"%29.%0A%09%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP131*%20%3Farea%20.%0A%09%3Farea%20wdt%3AP17%20%3FcountryId.%20%3FcountryId%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_label.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fcountry_label%29%20%3D%20"en"%29.%0A%09MINUS{%0A%20%09{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP137%20%3FoperatorId.}%0A%20%09UNION%0A%09%09{%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%20%3Fnunciature.%20%3Fnunciature%20wdt%3AP137%20%3FoperatorId.}%0A%20}%0A%09MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP582%20%3Fendtime.}%09%20MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20wdt%3AP582%20%3FdissolvedOrAbolished.}%0A%09MINUS%20{%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP31%20%3FinstanceStatement.%20%3FinstanceStatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendtimeQualifier.}%0A%09%23%20Only%20countries%20that%20still%20contain%20the%20location%20%28ex%3A%20Pristina%20is%20not%20in%20the%20"Province%20of%20Kosovo"%20because%20it%20does%20not%20exist%20anymore.%0A%09FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20{%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP131%2F%28ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131%29*%20%3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP131%20%3Farea.%0A%09%09%3Fwikidata%20p%3AP131%2F%28ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131%29*%20%3FintermediateStatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement%20%28ps%3AP131%2Fp%3AP131%29*%20%3Fstatement.%0A%09%09%3FintermediateStatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3FendTime.%0A%09}%0A}%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fwikidata`